# ArcObjects diagram/object model?

Tags: arcobjects

Is there an existing object model diagram for ArcObjects? Something that can be printed out as a large poster.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For each namespace in the [online help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ArcObjects_namespaces/000800000002000000/) there is a pdf.

[image]

I sure think it would be useful if someone made a DeepZoom browser web app for these.  I guess the text search would be a bit tricky though.

Comment: Ah - I've used these in the past and they've been fairly helpful. I suppose, given the size of each, it's not reasonable to have a single poster covering everything!

Comment: Note: Some diagrams don't show everything but focus on the most commonly used objects.

Answer (score 9):

If you have the SDK developer kit installed you can find the diagrams here:

C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\DeveloperKit\Diagrams